# Remove strings in a line in multiline Excel cells if they do not start with a certain string

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, line-breaks, string-matching

I have a column of Excel cells that follow this format (the random strings are not in a fixed order). Strings that don't start with a certain string need to be removed.

```
randomstringA text_that_needs_to_be_kept1
text_that_needs_to_be_removed1
randomstringB text_that_needs_to_be_kept2
randomstringA text_that_needs_to_be_kept3
text_that_needs_to_be_removed2
```

I want the cell's output to be this (linebreak must be kept):

```
text_that_needs_to_be_kept1

text_that_needs_to_be_kept2
text_that_needs_to_be_kept3
```

And not this (linebreak got removed):

```
text_that_needs_to_be_kept1
text_that_needs_to_be_kept2
text_that_needs_to_be_kept3
```

Comment: So - what is the specific problem you're having when implementing this?  What did you try and what happened?  One approach might be to use `Split()` on `vbLf` to get an array of lines, then loop over the array, setting the lines you don't want to an empty string, then `Join()` the array to get your result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will go down column A starting in row 1 and remove any line that doesn't start with a value from the array `arrToKeep`, keeping the linebreaks.

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveStrings()
Dim rngData As Range
Dim arrData As Variant
Dim arrLines As Variant
Dim arrToKeep As Variant
Dim idx1 As Long
Dim idx2 As Long
Dim idxRow As Long
Dim boolKeep As Boolean

    arrToKeep = Array("randomstringA", "randomstringB")

    Set rngData = Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    arrData = rngData.Value

    For idxRow = LBound(arrData, 1) To UBound(arrData, 1)

        arrLines = Split(arrData(idxRow, 1), vbLf)

        For idx1 = LBound(arrLines) To UBound(arrLines)
        
            boolKeep = False
            
            For idx2 = LBound(arrToKeep) To UBound(arrToKeep)
                If arrLines(idx1) Like arrToKeep(idx2) & "*" Then
                    boolKeep = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next idx2
            
            If Not boolKeep Then
                arrLines(idx1) = ""
            End If
            
        Next idx1

        arrData(idxRow, 1) = Join(arrLines, vbLf)

    Next idxRow

    rngData.Value = arrData

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In B1 place this formula `=IF(LEFT(A1;1)="r";MID(A1;FIND(" ";A1;1)+1;500);"")` and copy+paste to the other cells in column B.